# Well-defined momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, potential-energy

I have a question which states:

> Show that a particle can have a well-defined momentum in every energy eigenstate if and only if the potential energy is uniform in space.

I am completely unsure how to start. The Schroedinger equation states:

$\frac{p^2}{2m} \psi+V(r)\psi=E\psi$

$p^{2}=2m(E-V(r))$

but I am at loss how to actually prove that the momentum is undefined if the potential is varying.

Comment: Well, $p$ is supposed to be just a constant number, so the right hand side should be one too.

Comment: Show that it can only commute with the hamiltonian if it is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer starts with the observation that, if the particle has a well-defined momentum, then
\begin{align}
\hat p\psi(x)&=p\psi(x)\, ,\\
\hat p^2\psi(x)&=p^2\psi(x)
\end{align}
If $\psi(x)$ is an energy eigenstate, then $\hat H\psi(x)=E\psi(x)$.  Thus
\begin{align}
\left(\hat E-\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}\right)\psi(x)&=V(x)\psi(x)\, ,\tag{1} \\
&=\left(E-\frac{p^2}{2m}\right)\psi(x)\, .\tag{2}
\end{align}
For $\psi(x)\ne 0$, equate the right hand sides of (1) and (2), and divide by $\psi(x)$ to find $V(x)=E-\frac{p^2}{2m}=$constant.